# Create a sub array using map in javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have a JSON object that I need to make into an array and then create a sub array by passing in a value that will match an element

```
         [{"MemberID":1416,"PMID":"34274008","Member":"Frey, Lewis"},
         {"MemberID":1422,"PMID":"34274008","Member":"Welch, Brandon"},
         {"MemberID":262,"PMID":"34272328","Member":"Mohanty, Bidyut"},
         {"MemberID":1139,"PMID":"34272328""Member":"Howe, Philip"},
         {"MemberID":1444,"PMID":"34272328","Member":"Long, David"},
         {"MemberID":1665,"PMID":"34272328","Member":"Yoon, Je-Hyun"},
         {"MemberID":101,"PMID":"34270968","Member":"Silvestri, Gerard"},
         {"MemberID":101,"PMID":"34270965","Member":"Silvestri, Gerard"},
         {"MemberID":121,"PMID":"34270729","Member":"Carpenter, Matthew"},
         {"MemberID":1481"PMID":"34270729","Member":"Toll, Benjamin"},
         {"MemberID":1765,"PMID":"34270729","Member":"Rojewski, Alana"}]
```

I'm lost trying to create a very simple map function.  I need to create a sub array with "Frey, Lewis" and "Welch, Brandon" if PMID equals 34274008 or if I map PMID == 34272328 and get an array with 4 other names.  I've use map in the past with indexof but now I need an array and all of the other map's I've search are much more complicated that what I need. I'm sorry for asking such a basic question

Comment: First, [there's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/). Second, please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68643751/edit) to show clear examples of the inputs, expected outputs and what you've tried so far

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your comment. I'm just trying to help you get good answers and fewer downvotes on your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I think you're looking for** [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

`Array#filter` lets us return a sub-array based on a criteria that we specify, in our case `object.PMID = "34274008"`.

**This is what that looks like:**

```js
let subArr = data.filter(object => object.PMID === "34274008")
```

**Demo:**

```js
let data = [
  {"MemberID":1416,"PMID":"34274008","Member":"Frey, Lewis"},
  {"MemberID":1422,"PMID":"34274008","Member":"Welch, Brandon"},
  {"MemberID":262,"PMID":"34272328","Member":"Mohanty, Bidyut"},
  {"MemberID":1139,"PMID":"34272328","Member":"Howe, Philip"},
  {"MemberID":1444,"PMID":"34272328","Member":"Long, David"},
  {"MemberID":1665,"PMID":"34272328","Member":"Yoon, Je-Hyun"},
  {"MemberID":101,"PMID":"34270968","Member":"Silvestri, Gerard"},
  {"MemberID":101,"PMID":"34270965","Member":"Silvestri, Gerard"},
  {"MemberID":121,"PMID":"34270729","Member":"Carpenter, Matthew"},
  {"MemberID":1481,"PMID":"34270729","Member":"Toll, Benjamin"},
  {"MemberID":1765,"PMID":"34270729","Member":"Rojewski, Alana"}
]

let subArr = data.filter(object => object.PMID === "34274008")

console.log(subArr)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of object to handle the result data:

```js
let arr = [
    { "MemberID": 1416, "PMID": "34274008", "Member": "Frey, Lewis" },
    { "MemberID": 1422, "PMID": "34274008", "Member": "Welch, Brandon" },
    { "MemberID": 262, "PMID": "34272328", "Member": "Mohanty, Bidyut" },
    { "MemberID": 1139, "PMID": "34272328", "Member": "Howe, Philip" },
    { "MemberID": 1444, "PMID": "34272328", "Member": "Long, David" },
    { "MemberID": 1665, "PMID": "34272328", "Member": "Yoon, Je-Hyun" },
    { "MemberID": 101, "PMID": "34270968", "Member": "Silvestri, Gerard" },
    { "MemberID": 101, "PMID": "34270965", "Member": "Silvestri, Gerard" },
    { "MemberID": 121, "PMID": "34270729", "Member": "Carpenter, Matthew" },
    { "MemberID": 1481, "PMID": "34270729", "Member": "Toll, Benjamin" },
    { "MemberID": 1765, "PMID": "34270729", "Member": "Rojewski, Alana" }
];


let resultObj = {};
arr.forEach((item, index) => {
    if(resultObj[item['PMID']]) {
        resultObj[item['PMID']].push(item);
    }
    else {
        resultObj[item['PMID']] = [item];
    }
})
console.log(resultObj)
```

**Or the shorthand way:**

```js
let arr = [
    { "MemberID": 1416, "PMID": "34274008", "Member": "Frey, Lewis" },
    { "MemberID": 1422, "PMID": "34274008", "Member": "Welch, Brandon" },
    { "MemberID": 262, "PMID": "34272328", "Member": "Mohanty, Bidyut" },
    { "MemberID": 1139, "PMID": "34272328", "Member": "Howe, Philip" },
    { "MemberID": 1444, "PMID": "34272328", "Member": "Long, David" },
    { "MemberID": 1665, "PMID": "34272328", "Member": "Yoon, Je-Hyun" },
    { "MemberID": 101, "PMID": "34270968", "Member": "Silvestri, Gerard" },
    { "MemberID": 101, "PMID": "34270965", "Member": "Silvestri, Gerard" },
    { "MemberID": 121, "PMID": "34270729", "Member": "Carpenter, Matthew" },
    { "MemberID": 1481, "PMID": "34270729", "Member": "Toll, Benjamin" },
    { "MemberID": 1765, "PMID": "34270729", "Member": "Rojewski, Alana" }
];


let resultObj = {};
arr.forEach((item, index) => {
    (resultObj[item['PMID']]) ? resultObj[item['PMID']].push(item) : resultObj[item['PMID']] = [item];
})



console.log(resultObj)
```

Comment: This is an improper use of map(). If you just want a loop use `forEach()` or a for loop. map() is the wrong tool for the job

Comment: You are right. I've updated the code to use foreach loop. :)